# How to update state so it's reflected in child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, state

I am learning React and now I am making a very basic shopping list app. I wanted to increment the amount of existing items in the list, instead of adding duplicating items (with the same name).

I have the following component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ShoppingForm from './ShoppingForm';
import ShoppingList from './ShoppingList';

function Shopping() {
  const [shoppingList, setShoppingList] = useState([]);

  const addHandler = ({title, amount}) => {
    const existingIndex = shoppingList.findIndex(item => item.title === title);
    const item = shoppingList[existingIndex];
    if (item) {
      item.amount = item.amount + amount;
      setShoppingList( prevShoppingList => [ ...prevShoppingList.slice(0, existingIndex), item, ...prevShoppingList.slice(existingIndex + 1) ] );
    } else {
      setShoppingList( prevShoppingList => [...prevShoppingList, {id: Math.random().toString(), title, amount}] );
    }
  };

  const removeHandler = (removeId) => {
    const fIlteredList = shoppingList.filter(item => item.id !== removeId);
    setShoppingList(fIlteredList);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ShoppingForm onAddItem={addHandler}/>
      <section>
        <ShoppingList items={shoppingList} onRemoveItem={removeHandler}/>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Shopping;
```

It works. However, I am wondering if there's a more intuitive/easier to read way of writing this line

```
setShoppingList( prevShoppingList => [ ...prevShoppingList.slice(0, existingIndex), item, ...prevShoppingList.slice(existingIndex + 1) ] );
```

I tried to use something like just `setShoppingList(items)` but this way the child component `ShoppingList` doesn't update amounts, unless a new item is added to the list or an existing item is removed, then the amount for what's left on the list get updated as well.

This is my shopping list component:

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './ShoppingList.module.css';

const ShoppingList = (props) => {
  return (
    <section className={classes['shopping-list']}>
      <h2>Shopping List:</h2>
      <ul>
        {props.items.map(item => (
          <li key={item.id} onClick={props.onRemoveItem.bind(this, item.id)}>
            {/* <span>{item.id}</span> */}
            <span>{item.title}</span>
            <span>{item.amount}x</span>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </section>
  );
};

export default ShoppingList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shorten your construct with [toSpliced](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSpliced) method:

```
setShoppingList(prevShoppingList => [ ...prevShoppingList.toSpliced(existingIndex, 1, item)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const addHandler = ({ title, amount }) => {
  const updatedList = shoppingList.map(item => {
    if (item.title === title) {
      return {
        ...item,
        amount: item.amount + amount
      };
    }
    return item;
  });

  setShoppingList(updatedList);
};
```